# add property in collection view inside uitableviewcell

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview

I am creating a tableView which has collectionView inside.

what I did :
1. Created a table view inside a controller.
2. created a custom tableViewCell with collectionView inside of that and providing it with tag 
3. Created a custom collectionViewcell.

Now i made controller the delegate and datasource for both collectionView and tableView.

Now tableView should have multiple tableViewcells and each tableViewCell has CollectionView

One tableViewCell has one section.
Problem :-

```
 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

self.arrayModel = self.SlotsArray[indexPath.section];
}
```

But here is a catch : lets say my screen size shows two tableViewcell, then all methods of tableCells are called first and then all methods of collectionView are called instead i want that after 1st section of tableViewcell is created , it should call collectionView methods and create it. then go to tableView method make 2nd section and then create its collectionView.

Is there away to do this.

Somewhere i read on net thet i will have to subclass CollectionView and add a property index and then while setting viewcontroller  as delegate and datasource , set index also.

But i have created CollectionView By nib and adding it to the tableCell class by "TAG"

```
self.imageCollectionView = [self.contentView viewWithTag:2511];
```

Can you tell how can i achieve this?

Comment: I understand your question but I'm pretty sure you're bogging yourself into some nasty UI.
Technically, the tableview will create each row one by one. Since your custom cell has a collection view, each cell will then have it's own collectionview created.
I'm not sure your statement was correct. I'd have to verify but, I'm almost certain the tableview will create Cell1, and since cell1 has a collectionview, it'll create its collection view, and then only when its ready, the tableview will create cell2.
The only reason that wouldn't be happening is if everything was in the controller.

Comment: Or maybe I'm completely wrong in my assumptions

Comment: @Zil Yes both of the collectionView and tableView have there delegate and dataSource as viewController.

Comment: Why wouldn't the cell be the delegate/datasource of the collectionview? If the cell is holding it, it could be responsible.

Comment: The tableview cell could receive the array of items when you create it. If this array has > 0 elements, you create a new collection view and populate it, then display it.
You can forward all events (select, unselect, etc.) from the collectionview to the cell, then from the cell to the controller, and do whatever you want from there if necessary.

Comment: More importantly, there is no reason your UI should define how your data loads / behaves. The UI only reacts to the data, not the other way around. Maybe loading everything sooner might solve your issue. I don't know.
You actually asked for help but didn't tell us what is the underlying problem. Maybe it's something simpler or that can be solved differently than loading everything serially (and it should by default load serially, using what I wrote above)

Comment: @Zil I read on net you should never have cell as the delegate and datasource

Answer (score 1):

In your case, you should have one table view, having cells. Each cell will have a collection view inside it.

Number of table view cells will equal to the count of your data-source. As we all know, table view cell will be created one by one and assign each cell a data source which will be used to fill your collection view (which is inside each cell).

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{    
    CategoryCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:kCellIdentifierCategory forIndexPath:indexPath];

    NSArray *arrVideos = [parentArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [cell setCollectionData:arrVideos];

    return cell;
}
```

Now, inside that table view cell class, implement `setCollectionData` method to fill its collection view:

```
- (void)setCollectionData:(NSArray *)collectionData 
{
    self.arrCollectionData = collectionData;
    [self.yourCollectioView reloadData];
}
```

Now, each collection cell would be feed from this array:

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    VideoCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:kCellIdentifierVideo forIndexPath:indexPath];
    NSDictionary *_video = [self.arrCollectionData objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];

    // Use this dictionary 

    [cell.lblVideoTitle setText:_video.title];

    ––––––––––
    ––––––––––

    return cell;
}
```

Refer following image:

[image]

Hope it helps you !!!

Comment: Thanks for this, mate!

Answer (score 1):

You can take a look on this, surely it will help you to implement horizontal scrolling collection view inside uitableviewcell.

https://github.com/ThornTechPublic/HorizontalScrollingCollectionView/blob/master/GithubImages/videoGrid.gif

https://github.com/agusso/ASOXScrollTableViewCell